# Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

I have an Excel file where data is separated by a comma in a single cell. 
i.e. abc,def,ghi

I want to do a mail merge to a Word table where a new row is created when there is a column in the field data.
i.e.
table row 1: abc
table row 2: def
table row 3: ghi

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would just separate the values into separate cells before setting up the merge.  Do this:

Highlight the column that includes the data, go to the *Data* ribbon and select *Text to Columns* and choose *Fixed Width*. Click *Next* and insert a break line on each side of the commas and select *Finish.*  Delete the columns that include the commas and you're good to go.